# Shorten a method. Syntax better practices

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, coding-style

I've been learning via jQuery how to shorten things up. I was wondering if this script can be expressed in a less verbose way? I don't like how everything sits on one huge line.

```
   items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + ' (key: ' + key + ')(value: ' + val.value +         ')(type: ' + val.type + ') (range: ' + val.range + ') (clone: ' + val.clone + ') (archive: ' + val.archive + ') (access: ' + val.access + ')</li>')
```

Comment: Here you go -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mwRvR/) -> most excellent solution ?

Comment: You could build the string on multiple lins in a variable and items.push(myBigString);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the object will always have the correct key/values:

```
str = '';
for (var item in val) {
   str += '(' + item + ': ' + val[item] + ')';
}
$("<li>").attr('id', key).text(' (key: ' + key + ')' + str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/36Nyu/

Comment: This assumes val only holds these properties. You should also use val.hasOwnProperty(i);

Comment: @Kurt yes that assumption has to be made; why do you need `hasOwnProperty`?

Comment: So it doesn't look up the prototype chain, it's always better to be more explicit, in case there's a nasty Object.prototype.customFunc in there somewhere ;)

Comment: @ExplosionPills: You don't have to make any assumptions at all, because you have `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the assumption I mean is the one that all required values are defined (e.g. the `range` value is not missing).

Answer (score 1):

If `items` is another element, you can do something like this.

```
var str;

for(var i in val)
    str += '('+ i +': '+ val[i] +')';

$('<li>', {
    id: key,
    text: str
}).appendTo(items);
```

Comment: This assumes val only holds these properties. You should also use val.hasOwnProperty(i);

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery tmpl, or similar:

```
var template = '(key: ' + key + ')(value: {{value}})(type: {{type}}) (range: {{range}}) (clone: {{clone}}) (archive: {{archive}}) (access: {{access}})';
$('<li />').attr('id', key).html($.tmpl(template, val));
```

Or, use a string.Format equivalent:

```
String.prototype.format = function () {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/\{\{|\}\}|\{(\d+)\}/g, function (m, n) {
        /* Allow escaping of curly brackets with {{ or }} */
        if (m === '{{') { return '{'; } else if (m === '}}') { return '}'; }
        return typeof args[n] != 'undefined' ? args[n] : '{' + n + '}';
    });
};
var text = '(key: {0})(value: {1})(type: {2}) (range: {3}) (clone: {4}) (archive: {5}) (access: {6})'.format(key, val.type, val.range, val.clone, val.archive, val.access);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're appending all of the key/value pairs in the `val` object, doing something like this would be pretty maintainable:

```
var liPrefix = '<li id="' + key + '">(key: ' + key + ')',
    liSuffix = '</li>',
    liData = '';

$.each(val, function(k, v) {
    liData += ' (' + k + ': ' + v + ')';
});

items.push(liPrefix + liData + liSuffix);
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cY9yu/1/)